# Adaptive design is working wrong on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, adaptive-design

Here is the link http://testmvs.zzz.com.ua/, this is my test domain. 
I wrote this web-page, made it adaptive by myself (without any frameworks), in browser it looks i need, but when i'm watching this webpage on my iphone it looks wrong
I wrote meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1", why it looks different to desktop version?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your containers has a `margin-right` or `padding-right` that is why there is such an ugly white vertical stripe.

Try to use **bootstrap** for your project. It is a simple framework and works perfectly.

You can use `@media` to make your website look better. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)